# Volume Returns incorrect value MQL

Tags: mql4, mql, mql5

I want to get the real "Trading Volume" for a specific Bar but the return value of volume function and iRealVolume function are both quiet different from what i am seeing on the chart when clicking the indicators of volume in the main page.

for example volume[0] should show the data of 290000000 but it shows 13000000 instead. 
here is what i am doing to get the real volume of a bar.

```
double a = volume[0];
double b = iRealVolume(Symbol(), Period(),0);
```

i would like to know if any of you guys have a solution for my problem and your consideration is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, iRealVolume is indexed by a time series to do the same with volume call ArraySetAsSeries:

```
ArraySetAsSeries(volume, true);
```